# Cant pass EventHandler as parameter in C#

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, eventhandler

I get this error:

The event 'ListControl.SelectedValueChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Visual studio says 'c.SelectedValueChanged' is of type EventHandler

```
public Events ComboBox()
{
    var c = new ComboBox();
    return new Events(c,c.SelectedValueChanged); //Error
}


...


public class Events
{
    public object control
    public object events;

    public Events(Control c,EventHandler e)
    {
        control = c;
        events = e;
    }
}
```

Comment: var evs =  ComboBox(); so that i can later do evs.events += someEventHandler;

Comment: And if i cant pass an event handler, why am i allowed to make a function that takes them as input parameter?

Comment: It's supposed to go the other way: `combobox.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(someFunction);`

Comment: There is plenty of examples on this, for instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thats no different than what i said. By "someEventHandler" its obvious that its = new EventHandler(someFunction);

What im asking is how to pass "combobox.SelectedValueChanged" to some other object so it can subscribe to it

Comment: You CAN pass a EventHandler, but you CAN NOT pass an "event which returns a EventHandler". This answer tell you how and why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994487/2471080